Trouble backing up RDS MySQL database to my S3 bucket via Lambda function
I'm able to connect to my RDS MySQL db, execute a SQL query, process this query into a string (called backup). But then am unable to 'put' my backup data into my S3 bucket. My lambda function just keeps timing out.
I added print statements thoughout to see where my code was timing out and it was at this line...
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key, Body=backup_data.encode('utf-8'))

I checked IAM permissions for my Lambda execution role and it has full S3 and RDS permissions and my S3 bucket policy has "s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:PutObject."
This is the S3 portion of my code below:
# Upload backup data to S3
    try:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        s3_bucket_name = 'db-backup-bucket'
        s3_key = 'db-backups/backup-{0}.csv'.format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))
        
        print("S3 Client:")
        print(s3_client)  # Print S3 client
        
        print("S3 Bucket Name:")
        print(s3_bucket_name)  # Print S3 bucket name
        
        print("S3 Key:")
        print(s3_key)  # Print S3 key

        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key, Body=backup_data.encode('utf-8'))

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Backup data uploaded to S3 successfully!'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': f'Error uploading backup data to S3: {str(e)}'
        }

For additional context, the "backup_data" variable was defined in my RDS connection sequence (backup_data = '\n'.join([','.join(map(str, row)) for row in rows])
